# How should I keep track of Buttons associated with a custom object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm making an App that will have multiple, identical, objects and I need to somehow keep track of the dynamic UI controls they create.

Example: I have 3 sets of 2 buttons and they are supposed to control a Player object, and when pressed I need to be able to figure out what Player object they are associated with.

My first thought was to make properties for the player object with the button ID's and compare the sender ID to that, but I cannot seem to get it to work right.

My Second thought was to make the Player object contain properties that ARE the UIButtons, ie `p.button1` however that seems like it wouldn't be a good coding pattern. does anyone have any ideas on ways to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subclass `UIButton` and give it a `Player` variable and set this whenever you create your button, then compare the sender's player variable to your player.

Edit: another way to do it would be to set each Player's `UIButton`s tags to the same thing. ie. for `Player1` make the tag for all the buttons associated with it `37` or something.

Comment: I think i will try the tag thing, i didn't even know there were tags, thank you.

Comment: all UIView subclasses have a tag property. :)